# NPM Error OpenSSL Configuration npm command does not work ANYWHERE

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, openssl

I use Node JS, like everyone else. Everything used to run smoothly. Creating a React App and starting it. But, recently, it has started to give me this error:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: OpenSSL configuration error:
> 48370000:error:8000007B:system library:BIO_new_file:Unknown
> error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling
> fopen(D:\openssl-1.0.2j-fips-D:\openssl-1.0.2j-fips-x86_64\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.cnf,
> rb)

I am running Windows 11 and have tried everything available on the internet, and ChatGPT. No solution.
A little help maybe?

P.S. I have already tried the already answered question to this but it doesn't work for me

Everything available on the internet